# Couldn't capture all the exceptions at once C#

Tags: c#, winforms, exception, xml-serialization, richtextbox

I'm de-serilaizing a xml file and I'm trying to capture all the exceptions art one using the below code but it's capturing just one exception. What is the mistake am i doing here??

Code:

```
StringBuilder exBuilder;
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    var fileName = openFileDialog1.FileName;
    mruOpenRseConfig.AddRecentFile(fileName);
    try
    {
        ConfigDeserialized = MyConfig.DeserializeFromXmlFile(fileName);

    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (ex is DataConsistencyException ||
            ex is XmlException)
        {
            exBuilder.Clear();
            exBuilder.Append(ex.Message + Environment.NewLine);

            RichTextBox richTextBox = new RichTextBox();

            richTextBox.Text = exBuilder;
            richTextBox.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;


            Form richMessageBox = new Form
            {
                StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen,
                ControlBox = true,
                Text = "Error in File",
                MaximizeBox = false,
                MinimizeBox = false
            };

            richMessageBox.Controls.Add(richTextBox);

            richMessageBox.ShowDialog();
            return;
        }
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: "it's capturing just one exception." What do you mean? Which exception is it catching? Which exception doesn't it catch? Are you expecting multiple errors in the XML file to result in multiple exceptions? That's not the way exceptions work.

Comment: I'm expecting multiple erros from a xml file. Then what should i do??

Comment: This code is catching all exceptions but the re-throw it in case they are different from DataConsistencyException or XmlException

Comment: I removed throw & i'm stil having the same problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There will only be one exception thrown by the code, so you can't catch more than one.

For example:

```
try
{
    throw new NotSupportedException();
    throw new InvalidOperationException();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //ex will always be NotSupportedException and never InvalidOperationException.
}
```

You cannot make the deserializer handle one exception then carry on - unless it's your own - in which case you would have to trap them as each one occurred, log them and then view them afterwards, or raise events for each one if you wanted to react to them as they happened.

**Exceptions** are used to break the flow of a program, so when one is thrown it will stop what is doing and break all other execution until handled. Because of this the deserializer has stopped running and aborted as soon as the first exception is throw.

Comment: IMHO, no, these are normally using in parallel comupting.

Comment: I'm totally confused, here could you please a bit more that what should i do exactly to capture all the exceptions and put in the RichTextBox??

Comment: @linguini Unless it is your own serializer then you will have to share the code for that and how to do it.